# (python) how can i split tuple variables?

Tags: python

from text file, i could import the result with this code:

```py
with open('filename.txt') as file:

    information = [tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(file)]

print(information)
```

result:

```
('   1.1   4.4   7.5   8.9  11.7  15.0  15.3  15.6  13.3  11.1   7.5   5.8        ',)
```

---

I want to split this tuple and the result has to be:

```
('1.1', '4.4', '7.5', '8.9', '11.7', '15.0', '15.3', '15.6', '13.3', '11.1', '7.5', '5.8')
```

when i use this code,

```py
splitting = information[1].split(' ')

print(splitting)
```

Error happens with

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Are there any other methods?

Comment: Can you share the data that is in the file?

Comment: Instead of using a tuple in your program, you can use a list. That has the 'split' attribute

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you converted the csv into list of tuples in this line:

```
information = [tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(file)]
```

which result in:

```
[(//...tuple 1...//) , (//...tuple 1...//) , ...etc]
```

you better just concat them if you dont want nested lists:

```
data_list= []
for line in csv.reader(file):
    data_list += line.split()
information   = tuple(data_list)
```